# Abobe Acrobat won't close after passing To Outlook

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, adobe-acrobat

Windows 7, Acrobat 10.1.9.22

Here' s the scenario... The user creates or opens PDF. They then go to either attach dialog which then opens Outlook email dialog. They finish emailing the attachment and switch back to the Adobe window to close it. Upon clicking the usual red "X" on Windows 7, nothing happens. Alt-F4 doesn't work either, neither does Ctrl-W to close the document. Adobe isn't really "frozen" because I can go to File->Properties and the dialog opens. It seems to be isolated to closing the app.

It only happens after sending and the outlook window automatically closes. I don't think Acrobat is aware of the email window closing, but is waiting for it to close. I tried to close the Adobe window while the new email window was still there and Adobe kicks me back to it. If I close the email and don't send then I can close Adobe. If I send, and the window automatically closes, then Adobe window will not let me close.

I have had 67 views with no responses in the official Adobe forum over the past week. It seems rather obscure and is isolated to only one computer on the network. Have any other admins run into something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this got moved to SuperUser, but either way the issue has been resolved. It ended up being two problems together. There were some left over registry entries that had to be scrubbed. Adobe Labs had a tool to help with that. Then I "repaired" Office 2013 using the built in tool. That didn't work completely, so after tons of digging, the most likely culprit was it being a 64 bit install. I didn't get a chance to test the 32 bit version, but moving back to the last version of Office, for the time being, has Acrobat happy.